# Php array vs Python array

Tags: php, python, arrays

I'm new in PHP.
Is there any function in PHP that let you get e.g. [2-6] elements in array?
E.g in Python.

```
>>>array = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
>>>print(array[2:6])
[2,3,4,5]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its called slicing ;P

as such you should look at php's `array_slice`